# I want to do Firebase sms verification, sms code is sent to the phone, but sms code is not assigned to the incoming variable

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application in Kotlin in android studio. I did firebase SMS verification. The code comes to the phone, but even though I assign the code to the incoming variable, the incoming variable remains empty.

```
class EnterPhoneCodeFragment : Fragment() {

    var gelenTelNo = ""
    lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
    var verificationID=""
    var incomingCode =""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter_phone_code, container, false)

        view.textViewKullaniciTelNo.setText(gelenTelNo)

        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        setupCallBack()

        view.buttonTelKodIleri.setOnClickListener {
            if(incomingCode.equals(view.editTextOnayKodu.text.toString())){
                Toast.makeText(activity,"ilerle",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(activity,incomingCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(gelenTelNo)       // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(this!!.requireActivity())                 // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

        return view
    }

    private fun setupCallBack() {
        callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                incomingCode=credential.smsCode!!
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {

            }

            override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                verificationID = verificationId!!
            }
        }

    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true)
    internal fun onPhoneNumberEvent(phoneNumber: EventbusDataEvents.TelefonNoGonder){

        gelenTelNo=phoneNumber.telNo
        Log.e("emre", "GelenTelNo: "+gelenTelNo)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
    }
}
```

`incoming Code=credential.sms Code!!`.

In this line, no sms code is assigned to the incoming Code variable. The variable remains blank (" "). Can you help me?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, e?.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {

                if (!credential.smsCode.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    incomingCode=credential.smsCode!!
                    Log.e("ERROR","Sms coming: ${incomingCode}")
                }else{
                    Log.e("ERROR","Sms did not come!:")
                }


            }



I did what you said and saw it in logcat. There was only this.
2023-02-20 13:41:07.308 9173-9173/com.yigitkula.instagramclonekotlin E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:

Comment: Have you seen these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748170/problem-retrieving-safetynet-token-7-flutter-firebase-phone-auth)?

Comment: No, I didn't see an answer. I couldn't find it my problem is not solved I don't think it's a connection error anymore. Because onVerificationFailed and onCodeSent functions are working. I put log.e in it and it works. However, the onVerificationCompleted function does not work. The log.e functions in it did not appear in LogCat.